# Unable to save scene using Makie julia ("There is no display that can show HTML")

Tags: plot, julia, makie.jl

I am learning Makie and I'm trying to create a simple plot and save the figure in VSCode. I am able to get the figure to show in the side but when I try to save the figure, I get the error that there is no available display to show HTML.

[image]

This is all the code.

Could you kindly help with this? I tried looking online but found no mention of an an error like this.

Comment: I think saving an image with WGLMakie is a bit finicky right now. It may be easier if you use GLMakie or CairoMakie for this

Comment: yes, that appears to work, thanks